# Trivial solution of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For the following differential equation:
$$y'+2xy^2=0$$

the trivial solution $y=0$ is a valid solution (as far as I know).

However, the general solution for this DE is:
$$y=\frac{1}{x^2+c}$$

For this general solution, there is no way to get exactly $y=0$.

How is it possible for the trivial solution to be valid but not achievable by the general solution, or did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: I think you are trying to apply existence/uniqueness for linear DEs to a nonlinear DE.

Comment: Also, when you separate the variables, you have to assume $y\neq 0$.

Comment: @ElliotG I just started learning about differential equations so I'm having a hard time understanding. For non-linear DEs, is it possible for the general solution to not include the trivial solution?

Comment: I guess I'm saying you can't really call your solution "the" general solution because there could be others. For linear DEs it turns out that solutions always form a vector space or a "translated" vector space (an affine space).

Comment: I.e., for nonlinear DEs of degree $n$, you can't necessarily expect the set of solutions to be parameterized nicely by $n$ constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace $c$ with $y_0=y(0)$, you get $c=1/y_0$ and $$y(x)=\frac{y_0}{1+y_0x^2}.$$
This formula is also valid for $y_0=0$ and gives the zero solution.

However now this formula does not express the solution $y(x)=x^{-2}$ at $c=0$.